# How to allow only my SPA to call my public rest API?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, rest, single-page-application, laravel-passport

I've a SPA (Angular based) published at my-example-domain.com and rest API (based on Laravel 5.3), exposed at my-example-domain.com/api.
All API are public, so unauthenticated user can use my Angular SPA and call backend API.

I would like to allow ONLY my SPA to call my backend rest API so, for example, nobody should be able to call my rest APIs through a rest client/curl.

How can I reach this goal?
What kind of authentication should I have to set up in my Laravel app?
Is [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript) the right way?

Comment: Laravel Passport is the token based auth system, and yes, I would recommend using it for your needs. Scout is Laravel's indexed based searching utility. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: @btl thank you, Passport is an amazing library, but which feature of Passport is best suitable in my case?

Comment: Personal access tokens. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#personal-access-tokens

Comment: But in order to use p.a.t., I've to authenticate the user. Am I wrong?

Comment: Nope not wrong. Give some more details about the SPA, does it have any user auth or other restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Your client is available to the public.

It runs in a browser, so all the HTTP requests it makes can be inspected by its users (i.e. everyone).

Anything you do to try to identify the request as coming from your client, can be inspected and replicated by anyone.

Comment: what about csrf_token?

Comment: @trullallero — That's a token you give away to anyone who asks for one and then require that they include in the next request. Since anyone can ask for one, people who aren't using your client website can ask for one.